# Random Number weirdness powershell question

Tags: powershell

I have written these two functions to get a random number 1 through 10 X number of times.

```
function randomNum(){
    $availableNums = 1..9
    $availableNums | Get-Random
}

function randNumXTimes($x){
    $global:rando = @()
    for($i; $i -lt $x; $i++){
        $rando += randomNum;
        $rando
    }
}
```

If I do the `randomNum` function it will always do what it looks like it should do, it will give me a random number 1 through 9.

Then I have this function `randNumXTimes`, if I run this function which calls the `randomNum` function it now produces random two digit numbers, they are only supposed to be single digit numbers.

What the heck?

> Example results from randomNum:  6 7 2 7 8 2

Example results from randNumXTimes which simply runs the randomNum function X number of times...

> (randNumXTimes 10): 7 12 20 25 30 36 43 45 51 53

My question is, WHY does this do this when it looks like it should only produce single digit numbers X number of times? How can I fix this?

Comment: you defined `$rando` as a **_global_** array and then added items to `$rando` **_without referring to the global scope. if you add `$rando.GetType()` just after your `$rando` line, you will see that it aint an array - it's an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you assign an empty array to `$global:rando` at the start of the function, you don't actually ever use it - please see the inline comments:

```
function randNumXTimes($x){
    # create global var "rando"
    $global:rando = @()
    for($i; $i -lt $x; $i++){
        # assign to local var "rando" - not the same as $global:rando
        # its type will be [int], which is why the numbers keep adding up
        $rando += randomNum;
        $rando
    }
}
```

The solution is simple, just don't rely on global variables:

```
function randNumXTimes($x) {
    for($i = 0; $i -lt $x; $i++){
        randomNum
    }
}
```

---

You could easily accomplish both things with a single function:

```
function Get-RandomDigit {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0)]
        [ValidateRange(1,2147483647)]
        [int]$Count
    )

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $Count; $i++){
        1..9 |Get-Random
    }
}
```